# Transfer SVN repository from Google Code to RiouxSVN

Tags: svn, google-code

I have repositories on Google Code and now I want to move these code repositories from Google Code to RiouxSVN.

Problem is I have no idea how to accomplish that. I had tried to use "svnadmin" and "svnrdump" but could not make it.

For "svnrdump" I got this error

```
svnrdump: warning: W200007: Target server does not support atomic revision property edits; consider upgrading it to 1.7.
svnrdump: E175002: DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
svnrdump: E175002: Unrecognized svn: revision property
```

I tried to create hooks/pre-revprop-change.bat file with content

```
exit 0
```

But problem remains as it was. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

CG's SVN is extremely old, you can't use `svnrdump` with it. If Google Code doesn't have ability to create dump in admin-panel, you still can use `svnsync` for creating local mirror of GC's repo, which you'll dump and load to RiouxSVN

Comment: I can create dump by "svnrdump" by this command svnrdump  dump -r0:HEAD [URL_TO_YOUR_REPO] > Your_dumpfile.dmp but when I try to load this dump into destination repo, I got above error

Comment: @user2481869 - mea culpa, it can be RiouxSVN is pre-1.7. Cat you ask RiouxSVN's support "How to solve"? Or select another SVN-hosting

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use gitsvn to suck all commits and rebuild a new svn/git repository.
It would take some time since gitsvn only use svn commands and not svnadmin commands but if you do not have access to svnadmin commands, that's a workarround.

Answer (score 1):

RiouxSVN is now using Subversion 1.8 and you can use svnsync to import an existing repository from google code or another SVN hosting service.

```
svnsync init https://svn.riouxsvn.com/target_repo http://source_repo.googlecode.com/svn
svnsync sync https://svn.riouxsvn.com/target_repo
```