# Filter then transfer dumped SVN repository to riouxsvn

Tags: svn, svndumpfilter

I have a .dump file made from running svndump followed by svndumpfilter because I wish to exclude certain paths.  I am using svn version 1.8 on CentOS. I would like to import that filtered file into a newly created svn repository on riouxsvn.  I tried with this syntax (note "share-this.dump is a local file") :

```
svnrdump load https://svn.riouxsvn.com/(reponame)  < share-this.dump
```

and received the following error message:

```
svnrdump: E175002: DAV request failed; it's possible that the
repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
svnrdump: E175002: Revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hook
(exit code 1) with output:
The subcommand "svn:rdump-lock" is prohibited by RiouxSVN.
```

I have created the repo on riouxsvn without trunks/tags/branches. Nothing has been committed there yet.

I tried activating the 'hooks' on riouxsvn but I am not sure how to use this
to solve the error message above.

Does Riouxsvn support svnrdump or only [svnsync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34183685) ?

The only idea I have is to make a new temporary local svn repo, import my filtered content there, and then sync that across to riouxsvn.

Regarding the filtering step, the syntax I used was based on the [example in the SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.commands.c.exclude.html):

```
svndumpfilter exclude --pattern --targets ex.txt < complete.dump > share-this.dump
```

where the ex.txt file contained a list of the exclusion patterns, one per line, like this

```
/trunk/project/secret*
/tags/*/project/secret*
*secret_file.pas
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Disclamer: im working at RiouxSVN

Hello Chloe, we investigated your request for the usage of the "svnrdump" command and we decided to allow it for all the repositories.

It was indeed blocked in the revprop commit hook until today. Now, both of these commands are allowed on RiouxSVN:

```
svnrdump dump < repository URL >
svnrdump load < repository URL >
```

Also, make sure you have enough free space in your destination repository for your dump, or the post commit hook will deny the dump.

Thank you for bringing this matter to our attention!